# Determine status of application via SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to make a application monitoring system, and I want to know if there is any way to know, via an SQL server, the status of a given application connected to said server. In a way where if the application were to crash, a table from inside the SQL Server could detect it and update a row from the table with its status.
Other ideas are welcome as well, I just need a way to know if an application has crashed and somehow update data with that status.

I've tried searching for a way to send continuous pings to the server, and once the server stopped receiving the pings, it would change the status of the application inside a table. However, I didn't really know how to do it or understood how to implement it to my application; so I scrapped the idea.

Comment: ...SQL Server is inappropriate for this kind of task. Also, you're reinventing the wheel: Windows already comes with process monitoring via MDM and Group Policy.

Comment: You can change the application to write status to the database in case of crash or any unhandled exception.

Comment: If your service is clustered. You need to monitor your service status. If the service is abnormally written to the sqlserver database, you can find out whether Microsoft has a product to realize the monitoring service function on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless the application should always be connected to the SQL instance and detecting it isn't connected anymore is enough to detect a crash. If you want to check connected sessions you can use sys.dm_exec_sessions or sys.sysprocesses.

Another thing I've done before is importing the Windows event viewer logs. I know it can be done locally and using powershell you should be able to do it remotely as well, with the proper rights ofc. You can find an example here: https://mikesdatawork.wordpress.com/2020/03/31/use-sql-to-import-and-query-windows-server-application-logs/

But in general SQL server isn't the right platform to do monitoring and event collection. I think Grafana is a data platform better suited for this, you might want to look into it. I've experience with using it but not setting it up so I'm not sure how flexible it is.